# How to Test if exists a Method inside a Property?

Tags: php, methods, error-handling

**how to test this without throwing error or use the "@"?**

**can be valid:**

```
$foo->bar_x;
```

**or**

```
$foo->bar()->x();
```

i need something like:

```
if(($foo->bar()->x()))
   echo $foo->bar()->x();

if(($foo->bar_x))
   echo $foo->bar_x();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$bar = $foo->bar();
if (method_exists($bar, 'x')) {
    echo $bar->x();
}

if (property_exists($foo, 'bar_x')) {
    echo $foo->bar_x;
}
```

Of course, dealing with objects whose type you don't even know well enough to be able to call methods on them is not good. It should be clear what class an object is of and what kind of object a method will return and hence what methods and properties are available. Defined interfaces are a key point of OOP.

At most you should decide what to call based on the kind of object it is:

```
if ($foo instanceof SomeClass) {
    $foo->bar();
} else if ($foo instanceof SomeDefinedInterface) {
    $foo->baz();
}
```

Preferably you don't have that ambiguity at all by only dealing with objects of known types:

```
function (SomeClass $foo) {
    $foo->bar();
}
```